# read udp <<>>: i/o timeout / dns: overflowing header size

Tags: docker, kubernetes

tengo un problema en mi cluster de kubernetes, cada vez que un servicio se intenta conectar a la base de datos me sale este error en el pod del servicio:
read udp <<>>: i/o timeout
y en otra linea el error de connection refused.
En el pod del coredns me sale ERROR:  dns: overflowing header size.
Me parece que puede deberse a un loop a la hora de llamar a una direccion IP, pero no estoy segura. He probado comentar la linea de loop del dns, reiniciar el cluster, limpiar la data y el cache desde docker pero no sé. El error sale tanto conecctandose por docker o de forma local puesto que son servicios de golang.
Cualquier idea se las agradecere mucho.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.